Twilio Outgoing call Transfer
I have integrated the incoming and outgoing call by using twilio java script sdk and also implemented the outgoing call transfer. I have checked the Twilio API response. It creates the iterations. For example, I have logged in with 'rohit' (number assigned to Rohit +158********) on web browser (I'm using the token and identity for making and receiving the call). I retrieve employee details and initiate a call to the customer number "+9179********". Twilio acts as a middleman between the caller and receiver, creating a dynamic connection between Rohit (+158********) and the customer number (+9179********). The call is now ringing on "+9179********", and once the receiver picks up, the call status is ongoing.
Now, "rohit" (+158********) transfers the ongoing call to 'Kevinemp'. In this case, Twilio establishes the connection between Rohit (+158********) and 'Kevinemp'. In the Kevin dashboard, the incoming call will display with Rohit's details instead of "+9179********" (customer number). We want to create the connection  "+9179********" (customer number). to "Kevinemp".
I tried to find an API to retrieve details for the customer number +9179******** on the 'Kevinemp' dashboard when 'rohit' transfers a call to 'Kevinemp', but unfortunately, I couldn't find any API or alternative solution to fulfill my requirement.

Can you describe what you've already tried? It seems to me you try to build a warm transfer. There is a slightly outdated post about this topic but it might help you to understand how to leverage a conference call for this.

We have some similar cases here.
In these cases, we use Twilio conference instead of transfer call.
We include the A and B end of the call in a conference. To change participants, with the conference, we have the freedom to delete or add participants
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/conference
